# How to measure the performance of an Ionic 3 app?

Tags: performance, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have developed an app using Ionic 3 framework. I would like to measure the CPU and memory usage of my app. What is the best practice to do so?

Comment: Use AndroidStudio and XCode to measure the indicators you mentioned. Use the Chrome Developer tools if you want to measure the performance of you web-application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **must not** use `AndroidStudio` and `XCode` to measure the memory usage of the **Ionic app**.

**Why?** Here is the comment from [**Ionic team member**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11570#issuecomment-301507765)

> Unfortunately we have not been able to reproduce this issue on our
>   end. Would you mind checking your app on your device with safari dev
>   tools instead of the memory tool in xcode? The reason I recommend this
>   is because the xcode memory tools can be misleading in the fact that
>   it's not actually measuring memory usage of the javascript heap of the
>   app, instead, it is reading the memory used by the kernel / OS itself.
>   So based off the same concept I described here, the OS will not free
>   up memory used by the JS virtual machine if it 1. thinks the action
>   that used that memory is going to happen often and 2. thinks that it
>   has plenty of memory to spare. So, while the JS heap memory will be
>   shrinking every time the JS engine runs garbage collection, that does
>   not mean that the memory that iOS has allocated to the browser will
>   shrink, and, if iOS did start freeing up memory when it has plenty of
>   memory available you would actually see performance issues. Also, it's
>   important to remember that high memory usage does not === a memory
>   leak and in fact operating systems are built to take the most
>   advantage of the resources (in this case ram) available to it,
>   especially on mobile devices.

**Tools:**

[**Safari dev tools**](https://webkit.org/blog/6425/memory-debugging-with-web-inspector/)

[image]

[**Chrome dev tools**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/)

[image]