# Ionic 2 / Ionic 3 - Garbage Collection

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, garbage-collection, ionic3

I'm trying to get a better understanding of `ionic2` and `ionic3`.

How does the Garbage Collection work in ionic?

- What gets cached and when?
- How can we clear this cache?
- How do we set up elements for G.C.?
- Do we even need to setup elements for G.C?
- Can we/Do we need to setup pages for G.C.?

Like seen in this picture ([source](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-video-video-memory-leak-garbage-collection-solved/52333)):

[image]

Some of the memory gets G.C'd when going to a new page. However the memory is still significantly higher than before any video had been played.

Comment: See this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46229486/1077309

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK I'm gonna give this one a try:

- Ionic itself has not much to do with GC, there are no scheduled runs of a task that cleans up behind you. The only thing ionic (or more specifically the dev team behind ionic) has to do is to design and implement their UI components in way they do not eat up too much memory and also realease unused memory. Especially with Virtual-Scroll there have been issues with memory-leaks and so on.
- So lets go a level deeper: Angular! Same point as with ionic. The devs of Angular are responsible for how much memory is used by their framework. But Angular provides a *very* useful method `ngOnDestroy()`. Why is this method important to you as an app developer? Because it gives you the chance to clean up behind yourself. This method is called just before your component is destroyed, what does that mean? You do not need your allocated objects, arrays, **video-elements** (set `src=''` and then call `load()`), etc. anymore and you can release the memory. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800440/javascript-and-garbage-collection) are good reads on how to free memory. However as the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#ondestroy) for `onDestory()` mention you only have to release memory that is not cleaned up by the automic GC (subscriptions, media-elements, ...). Which brings us to the next level:
- Javascript/Browser: This is where the "real" GC happens. Javascript uses a *mark-and-sweep garbage collecotor* (all modern browsers ship with one), you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/864544/6184203). It runs every now and then and releases every object that is unreachable/not referenced anymore, to explicitly mark an object for GC use the `delete` keyword. The following image visualizes the mark and sweep process:

[image: Javascript mark and sweep algorithm]

> Image taken from [this article](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-memory-management-how-to-handle-4-common-memory-leaks-3f28b94cfbec), it explains how javascript memory management works in very great detail, I strongly
>   recommend reading it.

- And of course you always have the native GC of Java/Obj-C which cleans up the native part of the app.

Comment: Nice answer! I'd like to add that specifically on iOS, since the OS manages the usage of the RAM memory, sometimes some _resources_ are not released when they are not used anymore (because the OS knows that there's plenty of memory still available and does not know if that resource is not going to be used again in the future). I mention that because it may seems like there is a memory leak in the XCode inspector, but it actually may not be a memory leak at all.

Comment: Thanks for your addition, thats good to know! Reminds me of another "phenomen" that appears on android-devices and is also related to the devices cleanup mechanism: when android devices are low on (RAM) memory your cookies, localstorage (baiscally everything that is not a persistant storage) will probably get erased - thats also why session-cookies are a really bad idea for hybrid apps. Theres a similar cleaning process for iOS devices, thats when you see the "cleaning ..." label below an app icon.